# Make Render Texture distorted/blurry?

Tags: unity, c#

I have created a function that clicks images in real time and these images are copied to render texture that is created. I am looking for a way to blur/distort/half-fade-out the render textures. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
 Graphics.Blit(Texture2D, renderTexture);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No issues, I have found a shader and added an alpha channel to it. Here is the shader if anyone needs it. It has properties such as blur, distort and alpha channel.

```
Shader "Custom/Distort_Blur"{
    //show values to edit in inspector
    Properties{
        //_MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB) Trans (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _BlurSize("Blur Size", Range(0,0.5)) = 0
        [KeywordEnum(Low, Medium, High)] _Samples ("Sample amount", Float) = 0
        [Toggle(GAUSS)] _Gauss ("Gaussian Blur", float) = 0
        [PowerSlider(3)]_StandardDeviation("Standard Deviation (Gauss only)", Range(0.00, 0.3)) = 0.02
    }

    SubShader{
        // markers that specify that we don't need culling 
        // or reading/writing to the depth buffer
        Cull Off
        ZWrite Off 
        ZTest Always

         Tags {"RenderType"="Transparent" "Queue"="Transparent"}
         ColorMask 0

         Pass {
        ZWrite Off
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        ColorMask RGB
        Material {
            Diffuse [_Color]
            Ambient [_Color]
        }
        Lighting On
        SetTexture [_MainTex] {
            Combine texture * primary DOUBLE, texture * primary
            }
        }

        //Vertical Blur
        Pass{
            CGPROGRAM
            //include useful shader functions
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            //define vertex and fragment shader
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #pragma multi_compile _SAMPLES_LOW _SAMPLES_MEDIUM _SAMPLES_HIGH
            #pragma shader_feature GAUSS

            //texture and transforms of the texture
            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float _BlurSize;
            float _StandardDeviation;

            #define PI 3.14159265359
            #define E 2.71828182846

        #if _SAMPLES_LOW
            #define SAMPLES 10
        #elif _SAMPLES_MEDIUM
            #define SAMPLES 30
        #else
            #define SAMPLES 100
        #endif

            //the object data that's put into the vertex shader
            struct appdata{
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            //the data that's used to generate fragments and can be read by the fragment shader
            struct v2f{
                float4 position : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            //the vertex shader
            v2f vert(appdata v){
                v2f o;
                //convert the vertex positions from object space to clip space so they can be rendered
                o.position = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            //the fragment shader
            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_TARGET{
            #if GAUSS
                //failsafe so we can use turn off the blur by setting the deviation to 0
                if(_StandardDeviation == 0)
                return tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
            #endif
                //init color variable
                float4 col = 0;
            #if GAUSS
                float sum = 0;
            #else
                float sum = SAMPLES;
            #endif
                //iterate over blur samples
                for(float index = 0; index < SAMPLES; index++){
                    //get the offset of the sample
                    float offset = (index/(SAMPLES-1) - 0.5) * _BlurSize;
                    //get uv coordinate of sample
                    float2 uv = i.uv + float2(0, offset);
                #if !GAUSS
                    //simply add the color if we don't have a gaussian blur (box)
                    col += tex2D(_MainTex, uv);
                #else
                    //calculate the result of the gaussian function
                    float stDevSquared = _StandardDeviation*_StandardDeviation;
                    float gauss = (1 / sqrt(2*PI*stDevSquared)) * pow(E, -((offset*offset)/(2*stDevSquared)));
                    //add result to sum
                    sum += gauss;
                    //multiply color with influence from gaussian function and add it to sum color
                    col += tex2D(_MainTex, uv) * gauss;
                #endif
                }
                //divide the sum of values by the amount of samples
                col = col / sum;
                return col;
            }

            ENDCG
        }

        //Horizontal Blur
        Pass{
            CGPROGRAM
            //include useful shader functions
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            #pragma multi_compile _SAMPLES_LOW _SAMPLES_MEDIUM _SAMPLES_HIGH
            #pragma shader_feature GAUSS

            //define vertex and fragment shader
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            //texture and transforms of the texture
            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float _BlurSize;
            float _StandardDeviation;

            #define PI 3.14159265359
            #define E 2.71828182846

        #if _SAMPLES_LOW
            #define SAMPLES 10
        #elif _SAMPLES_MEDIUM
            #define SAMPLES 30
        #else
            #define SAMPLES 100
        #endif

            //the object data that's put into the vertex shader
            struct appdata{
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            //the data that's used to generate fragments and can be read by the fragment shader
            struct v2f{
                float4 position : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            //the vertex shader
            v2f vert(appdata v){
                v2f o;
                //convert the vertex positions from object space to clip space so they can be rendered
                o.position = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            //the fragment shader
            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_TARGET{
            #if GAUSS
                //failsafe so we can use turn off the blur by setting the deviation to 0
                if(_StandardDeviation == 0)
                return tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
            #endif
                //calculate aspect ratio
                float invAspect = _ScreenParams.y / _ScreenParams.x;
                //init color variable
                float4 col = 0;
            #if GAUSS
                float sum = 0;
            #else
                float sum = SAMPLES;
            #endif
                //iterate over blur samples
                for(float index = 0; index < SAMPLES; index++){
                    //get the offset of the sample
                    float offset = (index/(SAMPLES-1) - 0.5) * _BlurSize * invAspect;
                    //get uv coordinate of sample
                    float2 uv = i.uv + float2(offset, 0);
                #if !GAUSS
                    //simply add the color if we don't have a gaussian blur (box)
                    col += tex2D(_MainTex, uv);
                #else
                    //calculate the result of the gaussian function
                    float stDevSquared = _StandardDeviation*_StandardDeviation;
                    float gauss = (1 / sqrt(2*PI*stDevSquared)) * pow(E, -((offset*offset)/(2*stDevSquared)));
                    //add result to sum
                    sum += gauss;
                    //multiply color with influence from gaussian function and add it to sum color
                    col += tex2D(_MainTex, uv) * gauss;
                #endif
                }
                //divide the sum of values by the amount of samples
                col = col / sum;
                return col;
            }

            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this repository on github named [GaussianBlur](https://github.com/keijiro/GaussianBlur)

simpleBlit.cs uses a simple function to blit and set a texture2D which is desired by you as the source of the blit functionality

```
void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
{
    Graphics.Blit(_baseTexture, destination);
}
```

filterTest then creates a material at runtime and sets your custom shader on it (the project includes a shader that may suit your scenario).

```
void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
{
    if (_material == null)
    {
        _material = new Material(_shader);
        _material.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;
    }

    RenderTexture rt1, rt2;

    if (_downSampleMode == DownSampleMode.Half)
    {
        rt1 = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(source.width / 2, source.height / 2);
        rt2 = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(source.width / 2, source.height / 2);
        Graphics.Blit(source, rt1);
    }
    else if (_downSampleMode == DownSampleMode.Quarter)
    {
        rt1 = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(source.width / 4, source.height / 4);
        rt2 = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(source.width / 4, source.height / 4);
        Graphics.Blit(source, rt1, _material, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        rt1 = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(source.width, source.height);
        rt2 = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(source.width, source.height);
        Graphics.Blit(source, rt1);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < _iteration; i++)
    {
        Graphics.Blit(rt1, rt2, _material, 1);
        Graphics.Blit(rt2, rt1, _material, 2);
    }

    Graphics.Blit(rt1, destination);

    RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(rt1);
    RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(rt2);
}
```